# RxJava with android repository pattern

Tags: android, repository-pattern, rx-java2, android-room

I am using `RxJava` with repository pattern, `Room` as database and `Retrofit` for getting data from api. Here is my `Dao`

```
@Dao
public interface SubjectDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(SubjectEntity... subjects);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertSubjectEntities(List<SubjectEntity> subjectEntities);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    long createSubjectIfNotExists(SubjectEntity subject);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM "+ DbConstants.SUBJECT_LIST_NAME)
    Single<List<SubjectEntity>> getAllSubjects();

}
```

Api call:

```
public interface BcsQuestionService {
    @GET("get/bTQwGnFsky?indent=2")
    Observable<List<SubjectModel>> getAllSubject();
}
```

And here is my repository:

```
public class SubjectRepo extends BaseRepo {

    private static final String TAG = "SubjectRepo";

    @Inject
    public SubjectRepo(DataManager dataManager, SubjectService apiService) {
        super(dataManager, apiService);
    }

    public Observable<List<SubjectModel>> getSubjectList() {
        return Observable
                .concatArray(getDbSubjectList(), getApiSubjectList())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }

    public Observable<List<SubjectModel>> getDbSubjectList() {
        return mDataManager.getSubjectList()
                .filter(new Predicate<List<SubjectEntity>>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(List<SubjectEntity> subjectEntities) throws Exception {
                        return !ListUtils.isEmpty(subjectEntities);
                    }
                }).map(new Function<List<SubjectEntity>, List<SubjectModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<SubjectModel> apply(List<SubjectEntity> subjectEntities) throws Exception {
                        List<SubjectModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (SubjectEntity entity: subjectEntities) {
                            SubjectModel model = new SubjectModel();
                            model.setId(entity.getId());
                            model.setName(entity.getName());
                        }
                        return models;
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .toObservable();
    }

    public Observable<List<SubjectModel>> getApiSubjectList() {
        return mApiService.getAllSubject()
                .doOnNext(new Consumer<List<SubjectModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<SubjectModel> subjectModels) throws Exception {
                        List<SubjectEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (SubjectModel model: subjectModels) {
                            SubjectEntity entity = new SubjectEntity();
                            entity.setId(model.getId());
                            entity.setName(model.getName());
                        }
                        mDataManager.insertSubjectListEntity(entities);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Currently I am using `concatArray` operator to get data from database and api. But Only want to call the api if and only if I get nothing from the database. And I want to save the data into the database. Which operator should I use to server my purpose?

In additional,
I want to update my view when data is inserted into the database. For that reason I will change this method

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM "+ DbConstants.SUBJECT_LIST_NAME)
Single<List<SubjectEntity>> getAllSubjects();
```

into this

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM "+ DbConstants.SUBJECT_LIST_NAME)
Flowable<List<SubjectEntity>> getAllSubjects();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following

```
public Observable<List<SubjectModel>> getSubjectList() {
    return Observable
            .concat(getDbSubjectList(), getApiSubjectList())
            .first();
}
```

This will not execute the second stream if you get a value from the first one.

There's a nice article about that [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/)

Comment: In this case, when data is inserted into the database `Room` won't notify the  subscriber to update the view cause the `first()`  returns a `SingleObserber`